# I can't use call google script function from sidebar with google.script.run.anyScript()

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

These are my code

sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function isChecked() {
        var checkBox = document.getElementById("switch");
        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        if (checkBox.checked == true){
          text.style.display = "block";
          google.script.run.chengeVar(true);//spelling error
        } else if (checkBox.checked == false) {
          text.style.display = "none";
          google.script.run.chengeVar(false);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <text>Select to Copy    </text>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="isChecked()" id="switch">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    <text id="text" style="display:none">Select to Copy is Ready!</text>
  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs

```
var runSelect = false
function changeVar(check) {
  runSelect = check
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QQpXN7NHYyK4w0Qmlf_jnlJFzuO9FsjDuozqgWCLHOk");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DR_VS_ABSEN");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(check)
}
```

I have to try  many times. But the changeVar() function never running. I've used *google.script.run.* but the function never show alert.

Comment: Spelling mistake, you have changeVar in gs file and chengeVar in html.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anees Hameed poins out, you have a spelling mistake.

In your HTML you have:

> `google.script.run.chengeVar()`

And according to your code.gs file the function's name is:

> `changeVar()`

So correcting this spelling mistake, should work for you. Unless you are receiving some other errors.